# What event is fired on page load / hash load

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working in jQuery Mobile 1.3, and I cannot find the appropriate event for this scenario.

I have a `<div>` #show_protocol which houses dynamic content. If the browser is left open at this page, and then is refreshed, no content is displayed (because the form submission that populates it has not occurred).

So, I'd like to bind onto an event, check if it's this particular page role `<div>`, and execute some code if so. I've tried binding to `pageshow`, `pagebeforeload`, `pageinit`, and none seem to work at page load. The code fires when the event is triggered through use of the app, but it is not fired on first page load.

Here's what I've tried:

```
$("#show_protocol").on( "pageshow", function(){ // swap in pageinit, pagebeforeload, etc.
    if ( $(this).hasClass("preload") ) {
        [..]
    } else {
        [..]
    }
});
```

Have also tried:

```
$(document).on( "hashchange", function(){
```

And as @Sudhir points out:

```
$(document).on( "pageshow", "#show_protocol", function(){
```

None of that works. I'm not sure what events JQM fires on browser first load?

My HTML is basic, should not affect functionality:

`<div data-role="page" id="show_protocol">[..]</div>`

Comment: it depends where you place js code.

Comment: @Omar it is wrapped in `$(document).ready( function(){});` just before `</body>`

Comment: you should not use `.ready()` in jqm. try placing your code inside page div. `$(document).on( "pageshow", "#show_protocol", function(){ `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sudhir for the `.bind()` suggestion, I was able to implement like so:

```
 $(document).bind('pageinit', function( e ){ 
    var $id = $( e.target ).attr( "id" );
    if ( $id == 'show_protocol' ){ // check which page is loading
        if ( !$("body").hasClass("preload") ) { // check if already loaded
            $.mobile.changePage( "#protocols" ) // redirect
        }
    }
    $("body").addClass("preload");
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

try doing:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#show_protocol',  function(){
   //your code here
});

instead of $(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

use

```
$(document).bind('pageinit')
```

Reference:: [jQuery Mobile Events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html)

Comment: Thank you for replying! Same symptoms... when accessing the #show_protocol div by using the app, it fires. When the browser is refreshed, nothing fires. I guess I need to trace what jQM events get fired when the browser initiates / DOM loads?

Comment: @SetSailMedia see added answer